# YOLOv3 Object Detection with Darknet for Windows (with GPU)

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, windows-10, yolo, darknet

I want to test darknet with yolov3, running in GPU (on windows), but i'm with some struggle.
I build the environment with CMake for Visual studio.
When i do:
c:\Repos\darknet\darknet.exe detect cfg\coco.data cfg\yolov3.cfg yolov3.weights data\dog.jpg

I have this error returned:
Couldn't open file: cfg/coco.data

I'm not sure if it is some problem about the construction of Opencv and Darknet, and the build of darknet.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible reasons:

1.
You are running the command "c:\Repos\darknet\darknet.exe" in an absolute path, but your following arguments are provided in relative paths. So when you start this command line from other directory, it can't find those files in proper places. Maybe you have to make all arguments with the prefix "c:\Repos\darknet". Or, simply remove "c:\Repos\darknet" and run darknet.exe directly in the above folder.

2.
The error might simply indicate the darknet couldn't find the file in the location "cfg/coco.data".
But, where did you get the source of your darknet?
My darknet is fetched from: https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet .
In my cfg folder, there's the file "coco.data".

Comment: I get the darknet in the same github. And you are right, the error is because i'm running in an absolut path.
I already solve that problem, but forget to delet my question. But know, i have a new problem :/  
The error know is the following:
CUDA status Error: file: c:\repos\darknet\src\blas_kernels.cu : fill_ongpu() : line: 859 : build time: Apr 29 2022 - 14:48:10
CUDA Error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device
Darknet error location: C:\Repos\darknet\src\dark_cuda.c, check_error, line #69
CUDA Error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device: No erro